# Can Page.IsPostBack property be used in Windows forms?? c#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am trying to use the "Page.IsPostBack" in my windows form project. I am aware that this can be used on web pages but can it be used in windows forms as well?
if so will I need to import  anything?

Comment: What are you trying to use this for??

Comment: Why do you think you need to use this property ?

Comment: Hi, I need to do something similar to this in my project (http://forums.asp.net/t/1387219.aspx) the only difference is that my project is windows forms based .

Comment: The only reason this example uses the IsPostBack property is to avoid reloading the data every time the user clicks the button. Just look at the code inside the button click handler, but of course the Session stuff is useless here.

Comment: alright I see, could I code something like that in my project or will that be a complete waste of time in my winforms project?

Answer (score 4):

No, those are two completely different paradigms.  IsPostBack is meant for stateless programming, whereas windows forms is stateful.

Comment: Alright, i'm quite new with c#.. Can IsPostBack be replaced with anything else in wins form that does the similar functions?

Comment: @user3321606: This has nothing to do with C#. Research stateless vs. stateful programming and read all you can about it. If you plan on doing any kind of programming, you must understand these basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Postbacks are used in web forms. .IsPostBack is not a member of windows forms so there is no way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified summary:

**WebForms** needs the `IsPostBack` property because the form is loaded every time it posts back (traditionally this was anytime a button was pressed, though now AJAX changes that a bit). Because it stored a serialised version of all data in ViewState, you didn't want to reload the data in a lot of cases (this proved to be a huge issue as ViewState massively increased the page data, something for another topic).

**WinForms** only needs the `OnLoad()` handler, as the form is loaded once and stays on screen, no matter how many times a button is clicked. You can close and re-open the form, but it is valid to reload the data in that scenario. In your OnClick handler you can decide if/when to reload any data as required.